# error on running the comand "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi"

Tags: apt, wireless

when I run the above command for installing my external wifi adapter I get this error " no valid OpenPGP data found." please help me

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpl4a519zl/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpl4a519zl/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 7036069A2F22E44A: public key "Launchpad PPA for Pilot6" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install that PPA? It is obsolete. I should have removed that PPA.

Comment: I need this command for installing my wifi adapter (DWA131)

Comment: is there any other way for me to install my wifi adapter

Comment: You don't need this command any more. I deleted that PPA completely. You can search for another solution with drivers for your specific device and your OS version, or ask a new question with `lsusb` output and other details.

Answer (score 2):

That PPA is obsolete and should not be added to your system. (as said so in question comments by Pilot6 themselves)

Do not use the PPA.  The lack of OpenPGP data is an issue only fixable on Launchpad, but since the PPA is obsolete, there's no need to fix this issue.

Comment: I think the key has expired. But I won't fix it. I am removing the PPA instead.

Comment: @Pilot6 that key is autogenerated by Launchpad, not *your* key itself.  Expired or not, the point is the issue doesn't need fixed in the current state.

Comment: I am using keys with expiry date when signing PPA uploads. That must be the reason. But no matter what it was, I removed the PPA already.

Comment: @Pilot6 **no** the "Launchpad PPA for [USER]" keys are all autogenerated by Launchpad, they aren't your user keys.  Your user keys for PPA uploads being signed are used to validate access to the PPA and that you can upload to the PPA, not the keys served by "Launchpad PPA for [USER]" keys for PPAs.  Trust me, I know how this has been set up after asking a ton of questions of Launchpad admins :P